# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request using httpclient and PutMethod

Tags: java, httpclient, http-status-code-400

After thoroughly researching on SO on this issue, I'm finally posting it in a new question.

The purpose of the code is too upload a file to a payment gateway for further processing. As per their documentation, the only information that is required as part of the header is Authorization and content type.

The error that I'm getting is **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**

Below is my code:

```
public class BatchProcessing {  

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String version = "31";
    final String merchantId = "merchantId";      
    final String apiUsername = "apiUsername";
    final String apiPassword = "apiPassword";            
    final String batchName = "B"+System.currentTimeMillis();

    final WMHelper helper = new WMHelper();

    try{
        // make the HTTP PUT request
        final HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        final PutMethod put = new PutMethod("https://cnp.merchantlink.com/batch/version/"+ version +"/merchant/"+ merchantId +"/batch/"+ batchName);
        final File input = new File("testbatch.txt");
        final RequestEntity entity = new FileRequestEntity(input, "Content-Length: " + input.length());
        put.setRequestEntity(entity);
        put.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

        final String authString= getBasicAuthenticationEncoding(merchantId, apiPassword);
        put.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authString);
        httpClient.executeMethod(put);

        System.out.println("Status::" + put.getStatusLine());
        put.releaseConnection();

    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getBasicAuthenticationEncoding(final String username, final String password) {
    final String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes()));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you print out put.getResponseBodyAsString()?  Sometimes an API will return more details about the error in the response body.

Comment: @Pace : Here it is:

    Authentication failed: The credentials provided in the header either
    - use an invalid character
    - use an invalid Base 64 encoding
    - exceed 70 characters
    Please correct the request then try to submit again.

I saw this earlier also using some online REST service. Tried resolving that using different password encoder as well, but still the same issue.